# Potential supervisor asked for description of previous projects

Tags: graduate-admissions

As above, I emailed a potential PhD supervisor and he has asked me to send him a CV and a description of some previous projects I've worked on.

I am wondering how long/detailed should this be, and what exactly is he trying to find out? So that I can try and tailor it to that.

The programme I am applying to is also a MS+PhD in a different subject to my undergrad ( moving from mech eng -> comp sci/robotics ), so a lot of my projects aren't totally relevant, should I still list them?